# Add a new element (tag) to a list in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that gets generated using the `GET` method (API Call).

```
dataset<-GET('www.ttttyyyyzzzz.com')
contents <- content(dataset)
```

I extract the data by using the following command 
`contents<-contents$response$data`. This creates a list. A list of list of list.

This is how the list looks on RStudio. [image]

In terms of looking at this as a dataframe, I have 8 rows and 42 columns. What I really want to do is create a 43rd column called 'Year' and add it to each of the 8 high-level elements. 
Therefore, the list would now be "List of 43" for all 8 of my elements.

@Ronak asked for a dput - I have created a mock up for the sake of this exercise. With the following command, I want to add a 4th element to my main list called 'p' with a common value of 25 across all lists.

```
structure(list(m = 1, n = 2, o = 3, structure(list(m = 3, n = 4, 
    o = 5), .Names = c("m", "n", "o")), structure(list(m = 6, 
    n = 9, o = 8), .Names = c("m", "n", "o"))), .Names = c("m", 
"n", "o", "", ""))
```

Comment: Where does a year appear in your data set?

Comment: It doesnt. Thats what I want to add. I want to make it a list of 43.

Comment: `structure(list(m = 1, n = 2, o = 3, structure(list(m = 3, n = 4, 
    o = 5), .Names = c("m", "n", "o")), structure(list(m = 6, 
    n = 9, o = 8), .Names = c("m", "n", "o"))), .Names = c("m", 
"n", "o", "", ""))`

Here you go. I want to add a 4th element called p for example with the value 25 for all lists

Comment: Unfortunately not. This has created a nested list within all the lists.

Comment: If you see the above image, lets break it down. I have 8 main datasets. Each of those 8 datasets has 42 attributes. I would like to add a 43rd attribute for each of my main datasets. This 43rd attribute needs to have a common value for all 8 main datasets.

Comment: Works! Legend! Namaste!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we can add a named list element by doing

```
lapply(lst, function(x) c(x, p = 25))


#$m
#    p 
# 1 25 

#$n
#    p 
# 2 25 

#$o
#    p 
# 3 25 

#[[4]]
#[[4]]$m
#[1] 3

#[[4]]$n
#[1] 4

#[[4]]$o
#[1] 5

#[[4]]$p
#[1] 25
#...
#...
```

---

Or with `purrr::map`

```
purrr::map(lst, ~ c(., p = 25))
```

**data**

```
lst <- structure(list(m = 1, n = 2, o = 3, structure(list(m = 3, n = 4, o = 
5), .Names = c("m", "n", "o")), structure(list(m = 6, n = 9, o = 8), .Names = 
c("m", "n", "o"))), .Names = c("m", "n", "o", "", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

If I got the aim well, we can use:

```
 plyr::llply(contents,function(x) rlist::list.append(x,p=25))
```

Comment: This is PERFECT! But how can I make it a named attribute. I want to call it "Year". When you say 'p=25', it hasnt named the element as p

Comment: @CuriousBeing not sure but let's see. Although replacing `p` with `Year` does work for me albeit not an attribute.

Comment: Is this what you need?  `plyr::llply(res,function(x){
  attr(x,"Year")<-x["Year"]
  x})` `res` is the result above and `p` has been renamed to `Year`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `base R`

```
Map(c, lst1, p = 25)
#$m
#    p 
# 1 25 

#$n
#    p 
# 2 25 

#$o
#    p 
# 3 25 

#[[4]]
#[[4]]$m
#[1] 3

#[[4]]$n
#[1] 4

#[[4]]$o
#[1] 5

#[[4]]$p
#[1] 25

#...
```

#### data

```
lst1 <-  structure(list(m = 1, n = 2, o = 3, structure(list(m = 3, n = 4, o = 
 5), .Names = c("m", "n", "o")), structure(list(m = 6, n = 9, o = 8), .Names = 
  c("m", "n", "o"))), .Names = c("m", "n", "o", "", ""))
```